# Dog has gray with blood vessels in eye

Tags: dogs

My friends dog looks like the iris hasn't formed properly. I can see what I think is the very back of the eye or even his brain. I see gray with blood vessels. I watched the dog and tested to see if the affected eye could see and he can, although I have not tried from a distance.

Is this something I should be worried about? The dog is an 8 month cross bull mastiff.

Comment: You're definitely not seeing the dog's brain, unless it has a massive anatomical anomaly.  Dogs' eyes are a bit different from ours, and the retina should be more visible than a human's retina would be.  If the pupil dilates properly, and the dog can see with it, it probably isn't a big deal.  If you're still concerned, see a veterinarian.

Answer (score 4):

I really, really, REALLY doubt that there's anything wrong here. I think you're just seeing the retina in a normal eye.  If you insist on worrying, ask the vet next time you bring the dog in, but seriously, if the dog has *ever* seen a vet they would have noticed anything that drastic.

(A touch of congenital cataract is also possible, but since we don't have a photo we're guessing. If the vet isn't worried stop worrying. You can ask the vet at the pup's next checkup.)